# getting the same sized user pictures from different services in meteor

Tags: facebook, twitter, meteor, avatar

I couldn't get [Bengot's avatar](https://atmospherejs.com/bengott/avatar) to work, it just never displays an image from a service. So I decided to get the image url's by hand. I only use the facebook and twitter service.

It was quite easy to do, but twitter's image is much smaller then facebook's. What would be the best way to get a similar image? Or a larger twitter image (twitter's image is just to small).

Answer (score 0):

From twitter's documentation here : https://dev.twitter.com/overview/general/user-profile-images-and-banners

It appears you can just change the `normal` in the url to `bigger` to get a 78x78 image, like this :

```
http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_normal.png
```

to

```
http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_bigger.png
```

Comment: ah, of course thanks @mininao  should've looked there. hrm, but if I wanted to say have a 160x160 I would probably need to use the imagemagick package?

Comment: I don't think that is mandatory, you probably can just scale the image with css